# Guardar variable en LocalStorage con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy buscando un método para Laravel como el método de localstorage.setItem de JS , necesito guardar variables de configuración en el navegador de el cliente. Ya que estas variables las usara para toda la web la cantidad x de veces que ingrese al sitio.

Si bien puedo realizar esto con JS me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de realizarlo con Laravel.

Comment: Lo guardas con JavaScript, por que LocalStorage pertenece al ambito del front, existe en el navegador. Laravel no tiene acceso al navegador web, solo genera el contenido.

Comment: Como ya te comentaron, `LocalStorage` se puede acceder solo desde el navegador, si quieres hacerlo desde Laravel, entonces la opción podría ser con cookies.